# Shell Script Error using Cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, shell-script, newlines

I got this error after execute shell script as below.

```
$ ./script_test.sh
./script_test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/script_test.sh: line 3: `for ((j=0; j<"$N"; j++)) ; do
```

Script below

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script will launch 10 simulations for each value of the PARAM1_LIST.
# Simulations results will be stored in folders named "myTest-i-j", where i
# is the effective value of the PARAM1_LIST for each simulation and j
# is the 1 to 10 repetition for each i.

N=10
PARAM1_LIST=(1 2 5 10)

for (( j = 0 ; j < $N; j++ )); do
for i in ${PARAM1_LIST[@]}; do
java -jar N3Sim.jar myConfigFile.cfg myTest-${i}-${j} $i
done
done
```

Comment: Hard to tell due to the formatting above, but it looks like you may need `#!/bin/sh` instead of `!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: The OP seems to have written a full shebang, but markup ate the hash.

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: You can add a `set -x` below the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line to get more debug information.

Comment: Also, I notice and error near `$'do\r`. That `\r` is a [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Maybe that line got written or copied from a place with other line endings than which your interpreter expects.

Comment: You have several Bash specific constructs: therefore your shebang should not be `#!/bin/sh`, but `#!/bin/bash`. Some systems use Bash as `/bin/sh`, but nowadays most don't, I'd say (e.g. all Debian derivates). Just because it works by chance on one system does not mean it will work when moving the script to other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script contains DOS newlines `CR` `LF` instead of Unix ones `LF`. `$'\r'` is a bash escape sequence for the `CR` control character which should not be normally contained in Unix text files. It was at the end of line 3 which is now the line 11 as you probably added the shebang sequence and comments later.

Solution is to convert the newlines:

```
dos2unix script_test.sh
```

Also please note that the script is using bash construct of array and the shebang should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just need to convert the script to unix format using cygwin. Everything I put in hash-tag just a simple explanation to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @leepyron I do not completely understand your comment. You can convert your script file using the `dos2unix` utility (as shown in the answer) which is [part of Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/packages/dos2unix/). If for any reason you cannot install the `dos2unix` package, you can use for example `sed 's/\r//' script_test.sh
 >script_test-converted.sh` or `tr -d '\r' <script_test.sh
 >script_test-converted.sh`. See [Alternatives to unix2dos conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos#Alternatives_to_unix2dos_conversion).

Comment: @leepyron **continuation:** By "hash-tag" you mean the *shebang* sequence `#!/bin/bash`? It is a path to the script interpreter which will read and interpret your script file when you execute it. For example Korn Shell script would begin with `#!/bin/ksh`.

Comment: @leepyron As I and Glenn wrote earlier: In your case change the `#!/bin/sh` at the file beginning to `#!/bin/bash` because your script is a Bash script.

Comment: Hi @pabouk, I'm not sure what you're talking about. I'm still new with all this thing. My purpose only to create a script to automate simulations for a list of values of a parameter and repeat each simulation N times. I'm using an open source software with .cfg file. Right now, the script is working flawlessly after I convert it using dos2unix command in cygwin. Thanks for your attention. This is the guide that I follow: http://www.n3cat.upc.edu/tools/UserGuide/UserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using bash features but using a sh interpreter. Change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`

To decomstrate:

```
$ /bin/sh
$ i=1
$ ((i++))
/bin/sh: i++: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using unix text editor vi:

open file in vi edit with `vi filename.sh` command;

type in vi `:set ff=unix` command;

save file with `:wq`

It will save the file with unix line endings.